# How to update chart.js using Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

What is the proper way to update a bar chart (chartJS) using new data?

With this code below, I can get bar graph to update with new data. But with closer inspection, it looks like the updated graph is on top of the original. When I hover my mouse on the graph, it is jumping back and forth between the old and the new. I am having a hard time understanding the docs..

Maybe it is my HTML?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form id="frm2">
        <h7> filter by dates </h7>
        <input type="button" onclick="runGraphButton(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount)" value="update graph">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="chartleft">
    <div id = "buildCountInfo-js">To:</div>
    <canvas id="buildCount"></canvas>
</div>
```

.js

```
//intial data
let countList = [3,4,5,4,37,8,4];
let dayCount = [1,1,3,4,5,3,2];

//updated data
let updatedCountList = [3,4,5,4,37,8,4,6,4,7,8,5];
let updatedDayCount = [1,1,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,4,3,2];

//run at page load
runGraph(countList, dayCount);

//run at button push
function runGraphButton(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount){
    runGraph(updatedCountList,updatedDayCount);
}

function runGraph(counts,days){
let ctx = document.getElementById("buildCount").getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: counts,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Builds per Day',
            data: days,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {stepSize: 1,
                     beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

});

removeData(myChart);
function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
}
```

Comment: edited .js to fix mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chart.destroy()` will destroy any chart instances that are created. This will clean up any references stored to the chart object within Chart.js, along with any associated event listeners attached by Chart.js.

So if you want to load a completely new dataset, you could call `chart.destroy()` beforehand. I refactored your code a little bit and this seems to be working:

```js
let myChart; // declare chart variable

//intial data
let countList = [3, 4, 5, 4, 37, 8, 4];
let dayCount = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2];

//updated data
let updatedCountList = [3, 4, 5, 4, 37, 8, 4, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5];
let updatedDayCount = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2];

//run at page load
myChart = runGraph(countList, dayCount);

//run at button push
function runGraphButton(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount) {
  myChart.destroy();  // call destroy before loading new dataset
  myChart = runGraph(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount);
}

function runGraph(counts, days) {
  let ctx = document.getElementById("buildCount").getContext('2d');
  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: counts,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Builds per Day',
        data: days,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }

  });
  return myChart; // return chart object
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="frm2">
    <h7> filter by dates </h7>
    <input type="button" onclick="runGraphButton(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount)" value="update graph">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="chartleft">
  <div id="buildCountInfo-js">To:</div>
  <canvas id="buildCount"></canvas>
</div>
```

Note I also removed the `removeData()` method since I'm calling `destroy()`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you the answer from @adlanArifZakaria seems to work also, but just a few more lines of code. Not sure of the benefit of one over the other? Either way the solutions work. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your update function to be

```
//run at button push
function runGraphButton(updatedCountList, updatedDayCount){
    chart.data.labels = updatedCountList;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = updatedDayCount;
    chart.update();
}
```